# Connection line between shapes is in wrong place

Tags: java, swing, graphics, geometry, shapes

Here is the scenario: I can draw circles and rectangles in a JFrame, and I can select them too (one-by-one, or two-by-two).

Those shapes are stored in an ArrayList of Shapes (there are 3 classes, Line, Rectangle and Circle, that extend a superclass, Shape).

It was working perfectly, but I need to add another feature. When I select 2 shapes, a line must be painted between, connecting them.

The problem is: the line is not being painted, even when I call `repaint()` method.

The codes related to the problem:

Shape class (superclass):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.*;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamOmitField;

public class Shape extends JPanel implements Serializable {
protected Point begin;
protected Point end;
protected int width;
protected int height;
protected int id;
@XStreamOmitField protected boolean full;
protected Color color;
protected String shape;
@XStreamOmitField protected boolean isSelected; 

public int getId(){
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}   
public boolean getIsSelected(){
    return isSelected;
}
public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected){
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}
public Point getBegin() {
    return begin;
}
public void setBegin(Point begin) {
    this.begin = begin;
}
public Point getEnd() {
    return end;
}
public void setEnd(Point end) {
    this.end = end;
}
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public void setHeight(int height){
    this.height = height;
}
public boolean getIsFull(){
    return full;
}
public void setFull(boolean full){
    this.full = full;
}
public Color getColor(){
    return color;
}
public void setColor(Color color){
    this.color = color;
}
public void setShape(String shape){
    this.shape = shape;
}
public String getShape(){
    return shape;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID: " + getId() + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() +  "Begin x: " + begin.x + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Begin y: " + begin.y + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "End x: " + end.x + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "End y: " + end.y + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Width: " + width + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Height: " + height + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Color: " + color + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Shape: " + shape + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + java.lang.System.lineSeparator();
    //return "ID: " + getId() + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() +  "Begin x: " + begin.x + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Begin y: " + begin.y + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "End x: " + end.x + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "End y: " + end.y + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Width: " + width + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Height: " + height + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Color: " + color + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "Shape: " + shape + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + java.lang.System.lineSeparator() + "New Fields: " + newFields + java.lang.System.lineSeparator();
    //return "Begin: " + getBegin() + "\nEnd: " + "\nWidth: " + getWidth() + "\nHeight: " + getHeight() + "\nFull: " + isFull() + "\nColor: " + getColor();

}

//Constructors

public Shape(Point begin, Point end, int width, int height, boolean full, Color color, String shape) {
    this();
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.full = full;
    this.color = color;
    this.shape = shape;
}

public Shape(Point begin, Point end, int width, int height, boolean full, Color color, String shape, HashMap newFields) {
    this();
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.full = full;
    this.color = color;
    this.shape = shape;
    this.newFields = newFields;
}

public Shape(Point begin, Point end, int width, int height, boolean full, Color color, String shape, boolean isSelected) {
    this();
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.full = full;
    this.color = color;
    this.shape = shape;
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public Shape(Point begin, Point end, int width, int height, boolean full, Color color, String shape, boolean isSelected, HashMap newFields) {
    this();
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.full = full;
    this.color = color;
    this.shape = shape;
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
    this.newFields = newFields;
}

public Shape(Point begin, Point end, boolean full, Color color, String shape) {
    this();
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
    this.full = full;
    this.color = color;
    this.shape = shape;
}

public Shape(Point begin, Point end, boolean full, Color color, String shape, boolean isSelected) {
    this();
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
    this.full = full;
    this.color = color;
    this.shape = shape;
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public Shape() {
    super();
    setOpaque(false);
}
}
```

Line Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

    public class Line extends Shape implements Serializable{

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setStroke(s);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        if((begin.x > end.x) && (begin.y < end.y)) {
            g2d.drawLine(0, height, width, 0);
        }
        else if((begin.x < end.x) && (begin.y > end.y)){
            g2d.drawLine(0, height, width, 0);
        }
        else g2d.drawLine(0,  0, width, height);
    }

      //Constructors
      public Line() {
         super();
      }

      public Line(Point begin, Point end, int width, int height, boolean full, Color color, String shape) {
        super(begin, end, width, height, full, color, shape);
      }
   }
```

A piece of code (working) that prints circles (inside a mouseListener):

```
                c.setShape("Circle");                   
                //Axis
                x1 = Math.min(mousePressed.x, mouseReleased.x);
                y1 = Math.min(mousePressed.y, mouseReleased.y);
                begin.setLocation(x1, y1);  
                c.setBegin(mousePressed);
                c.setEnd(mouseReleased);
                c.setId(count);
                c.setWidth(Math.abs(mouseReleased.x - mousePressed.x));
                c.setHeight(Math.abs(mouseReleased.y - mousePressed.y));
                c.setColor(choosenColor);
                c.setLocation(begin);
                c.setSize(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
                c.setFull(full);
                for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++){
                    if(c.getBounds().intersects(images.get(i).getBounds())){
                        flag = false;
                        }
                }                   
                if(flag == true){
                    drawPanel.add(c);
                    drawPanel.repaint();
                    images.add(c);
                    colors.add(choosenColor);
                    count++;
                }
```

And that's the part of the code broken:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                boolean found = false;
                int counter = 0;
                Line line = new Line();
                //TRYING TO DEBUG PRINTING THE LINE, BUT IT DOES NOT PRINT
                line.setColor(Color.RED);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line);
                for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++){
                //CHECKING IF CLICK IS INSIDE A SHAPE
                    if((images.get(i).getLocation().getX() < e.getX() && images.get(i).getLocation().getY() < e.getY() && images.get(i).getX() + images.get(i).getWidth() > e.getX() && images.get(i).getLocation().getY() + images.get(i).getHeight() > e.getY())){
                        images.get(i).setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        images.get(i).setIsSelected(true);
                        found = true;
                    }
                    if(images.get(i).getColor() == Color.BLUE){
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if(counter > 2){
                        images.get(i).setColor(colors.get(i));
                        images.get(i).setIsSelected(false);
                        found = false;
                        selectedImages.clear();
                    }
                }

                if (!found){
                    counter = 0;
                    selectedImages.clear();
                    for(int j=0; j<images.size(); j++){
                        images.get(j).setColor(colors.get(j));
                        images.get(j).setIsSelected(false);
                    }
                }
                repaint();

                if(counter == 2){
                    for(Shape s : images){
                        if(s.getIsSelected() == true){
                            selectedImages.add(s);
                        }
                    }
                if(selectedImages.size() == 2){
                    Point p1 = new Point();
                    Point p2 = new Point();
                    p1.x = selectedImages.get(0).getWidth()/2;
                    p1.y = selectedImages.get(0).getHeight()/2;
                    p2.x = selectedImages.get(1).getWidth()/2;
                    p2.y = selectedImages.get(1).getHeight()/2;
                    line.setShape("Line");
                    line.setBegin(p1);
                    line.setEnd(p2);
                    line.setId(count);
                    line.setFull(full);
                    line.setWidth(Math.abs(p2.x - p1.x));
                    line.setHeight(Math.abs(p2.y - p1.y));
                    line.setColor(Color.RED);
                    drawPanel.add(line);
                    repaint();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line.toString());
                    }                       
                }
                    selectedImages.clear();
```

> PS: When i print the line.toString(), it shows me all the right attributes.. strange.. for example:
>
> - ID: 2
> - Begin x: 68
> - Begin y: 45
> - End x: 73
> - End y: 37
> - Width: 5
> - Height: 8
> - Color: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
> - Shape: Line

Please feel free to ask more code if I did not make myself clear.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a screenshot that shows exactly what i'm saying. Look at the red line. The height and the width are correct, but the starting coordinates do not. The line should start at the center of the first selected rectangle, and should end at the center of the second selected rectangle.

[image: An example]

Comment: Try adding `System.out.printf("begin=%s end=%s%n", begin, end);` right before your drawLine.  Be sure those coordinates are within the visible area of your component.

Comment: Thanks for helping, @VGR. After adding this, and running a test, the console prints this:

begin=java.awt.Point[x=173,y=88] end=java.awt.Point[x=54,y=79]
begin=java.awt.Point[x=173,y=88] end=java.awt.Point[x=54,y=79]

Comment: The code looks overly complicated and convoluted. The `Line extends Shape` does not refer to [`java.awt.Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html), or does it? If so: Why is there a `paintComponent` method? A [MCVE] would really be helpful here...

Comment: Thanks, @Marco13! No, it does not. It refers to a superclass Shape, as I said. I will edit the post with this class, and some screenshots.

Comment: I think that when you call `line.setLocation(p1);` before doing `drawPanel.add(line);` it **might** seem to work, but there are **many, serious** flaws in that code. The fact that you override several methods (e.g. `setWidth`/`getWidth`) in the `Shape` class, and this will interfere with Swing, is only one of the most obviously problematic ones. You should *really* have someone review your full code if you have the chance for that.

Comment: @Marco13, I do not know someone that could help me with review.. I'm stuck on this problem.. maybe trying a `translate` to the center of the rectangle?

Comment: Calling `line.setLocation(p1)` did not work?

Comment: @Marco13 Unfortunately, it did not. I have added before but still draws the line starting at (0,0) in the top-left corner. It's very strange such behaviour.

Comment: Add lines like `p1.x += selectedImages.get(0).getBegin().x` for `p1` and `p2`, each `x` and `y`, before `line.setShape("Line");`

Comment: @Marco13 Still drawing at (0,0) in the top left corner. I just can't get why this is happening.. Drawing rectangles and circles is ok, but when i try to draw automatically this connection lines, it brokes. Would be a problem in the `paintComponent()` in `Line.class`? Or the problem is in the methods?

Comment: At this point, one can only guess. Again: The fact that you override `getWidth` etc. in the `Line` class may break things arbitrarily (besides the fact that you should not extend `JPanel` just to create a circle or rectangle to begin with...). You can try to step through your `paintComponent` with a debugger. Otherwise, a [MCVE] could be necessary. If this is a complete project that can be compiled **without** any other setup, you can also send me a ZIP of the whole project to `javagl` at `javagl.de`, maybe I can have a look (but I won't promise anything)

Comment: @Marco13 I sent you an e-mail with the whole project. Thank you so much for offering your time to help me! Currently I am debugging to find where is the error, but I just can't get it.

Comment: You don't need to call `setWidth` and `setHeight` if you already set the endpoints - they might be overwriting your chosen endpoint.